# How to get asymptotes of hyperbola using derivatives?

Tags: limits, analytic-geometry, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to get the asymptotes of a hyperbola of the form $f(x)=\sqrt{1+px^2}$. So I took the derivative giving me:

$${d\over dx}\left(\sqrt{1+px^2} \right)={px\over \sqrt{1+px^2}} $$

Now, giving that the asymptote lines $T(a)$ at some point $(a,f(a))$ of the graph is:

$$T(a)=f'(a)(x-a)+f(a) $$

I decided to take the limit

$$\lim_{a\to\infty}T(a)=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left({pa\over \sqrt{1+pa^2}} \right)(x-a)+ \sqrt{1+pa^2}$$

I tried L'Hopital's rule and didn't work.

Comment: If you divide the numerator & denominator of your formula for the derivative by $x$ and take the limit as $x\to\infty$ you get $\sqrt{p}$ for the slope of the asymptote. The $y$-intercept of the asymptotes must be $0$ because the hyperbola is symmetric across the axes.

Comment: @runway44 Do you say something like $T(a)/f'(x)$?

Comment: What? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @runway44 maybe you can post an answer for what do you mean. I was typing this question when I think using the method above so that's why a post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a do a substitution $a=1/u$, such that taking the limit when $u\to 0$ then:

$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\left({pa\over \sqrt{1+pa^2}} \right)(x-a)+ \sqrt{1+pa^2}$$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left({p(1/u)\over \sqrt{1+p(1/u)^2}} \right)(x-(1/u))+ \sqrt{1+p(1/u)^2} $$

$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\left({p\over \sqrt{u^2+p}} \right)\left(ux-1\over u \right)+{{\sqrt{u^2+p}}\over u}$$

$$=\lim_{u\to0}{{pux-p+u^2+p}\over u\sqrt{u^2+p}}=\lim_{u\to 0}{{px+u}\over\sqrt{u^2+p}} $$
$$={px\over \sqrt{p}} $$

And so$\dots$

$$\lim_{a\to\infty}T(a)=x\sqrt{p} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\sqrt{1+px^2}=\sqrt{px^2\left(1+\frac{1}{px^2}\right)}=\sqrt{px^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{px^2}}$$
Using the fact that $(1+t)^{\alpha}\sim1+\alpha t$ when $t\to 0$, and assuming $x>0$, you have:
$$ f(x)\sim x\sqrt{p}\left(1+\frac{1}{2px^2}\right)=x\sqrt{p}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{p}x}$$